# Optimize my Code logic without singletion

Tags: c#, .net, performance, singleton

```
 public interface IHandler
    {
        List<string> Run();
    }

public class Base 
{

    void methodA();
}

public Class Der1 : Base , IHandler
{
     List<string> Run()
     { //Generate huge records
     }
}

public Class Der2 : Base , IHandler
{
     List<string> Run()
     {//Generate huge records
     }
}

public Class Der3 : Base , IHandler
{
     List<string> Run()
     {//Generate huge records
     }
}
```

Currently Run() is getting executed across all the derived class and generating same set of records. I want this to optimize.

Move the RecordGeneration process inside Run() to a common class/function and get executed once and prepare the necessary records. All the Derived class will use this "RecordGeneration" to get the already Generated Records.

Note: I cannot implement Singleton pattern.

Comment: Wouldn't be better in [CodeReview.SE]?

Comment: Why `IHandler` isn't implemented in `Base`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private Lazy<List<string>> l;

public Der1
{
    l = new Lazy<List<string>>(() => Run());
}

public List<string> ResultOfRun
{
    get
    {
         return l.Value();
    }
}
```

To extend on my initial answer, if the method has the same output across all methods, you can do this:

```
public class Base
{
    private Lazy<List<string>> l =  new Lazy<List<string>>(() => RunStatic());

    private static List<string> RunStatic()
    {
        //
    }

    public List<string> ResultOfRun
    {
        get
        {
             return l.Value();
        }
    }

    void methodA();
}
```

Then you only have to call it in `Run`, which could be in the base class to if it implements the interface:

```
public Class Der1 : Base , IHandler
{
     List<string> Run()
     {
         return this.ResultOfRun;
     }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `l` should be static and moved to the `Base`, since results are the same for all descendants.

Comment: `l` can't be static since it uses instance variables. Second, the base class doesn't implement the required interface, while I would indeed prefer it does.

Comment: Ah okay. Now I see what you mean. Yes, it would be best to move it there and make it static.

Comment: Can you brief a bit more with my example?, I'm not able to understand on what you are discussing..

Comment: @user1581317 Okay. Updated answer.